# Accessing controller method from view in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I would like to call a controller method which is not necessarily an action from my view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the rendering controller using `this.get('controller')` in a view.

So you can do this:

```
var controller = this.get('controller');
controller.myMethod();
```